# What does error code -112 mean in Android

Tags: android, android-package-managers

I get the following error when I install an android app:
`InstallAppProgress: Installation error code: -112`

Above I see an error from the `PackageManager` which will be the issue, but I would like to know what -112 stand for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [sources](http://androidxref.com/7.0.0_r1/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/android/content/pm/PackageManager.java#1092):

> Installation failed return code: this is passed to the `IPackageInstallObserver` if the system failed to install the package because it is attempting to define a permission that is already defined by some existing package.
>   The package name of the app which has already defined the permission is passed to a `PackageInstallObserver`, if any, as the `EXTRA_FAILURE_EXISTING_PACKAGE` string extra; and the name of the permission being redefined is passed in the `EXTRA_FAILURE_EXISTING_PERMISSION` string extra.